# More examples that are elementary of GCD domains that are not UFD domains.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

**What are some more examples that are elementary of GCD domains that are not unique factorization domains?**

For my personal notes, I'm looking for examples of rings that belong to one rung but not the next in Wikipedia's hierarchy:

```
rngs ⊃ rings ⊃ commutative rings ⊃ integral domains ⊃ 
integrally closed domains ⊃ GCD domains ⊃ unique factorization domains ⊃
principal ideal domains ⊃ Euclidean domains ⊃ 
fields ⊃ algebraically closed fields
```

I'm trying to fill out each level with examples that are as elementary as possible.

I'm looking for examples of a non-UFD GCD domains besides [the algebraic integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1402131/) and [the ring of entire functions on $\mathbb{C}$ or the monoid ring $(k, \mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1229955).

One example that I thought of earlier today are the multiplicative functions from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$, let's call this ring $R$. Addition, subtraction, and multiplication are pointwise. **Multiplicativeness is a little bit of a red herring here, since I'm effectively just treating these functions as sequences of integers**.

These are the functions such that $f$ is constantly zero or all of the conditions hold:

- $f(0)$ is $0$.
- $f(1)$ is $1$.
- $f(n)$ for positive $n$ is $f(p_1)^{a_1}f(p_2)^{a_2}\cdots$ where $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots$ is the prime factorization of $n$.

The GCD of two functions in $R$ is defined componentwise on $(f(0), g(0)), (f(1), g(1)), \{ (f(p), g(p)): \;\text{$p$ prime} \}$. The GCD is only defined up to a unit, but that's okay because any multiplicative function with image $\{\pm 1\}$ is a unit here.

However, we can show that this function does not have unique factorization by considering the identity function $\text{id}$.

$\text{id}$ is an identity function under *composition* (temporarily disregarding the fact that the domain and codomain are not identical). However, under *multiplication*, which is pointwise, $\text{id}$ can be expressed as the following infinite product (temporarily disregarding the fact that $R$ does not have enough structure to allow us to take limits):

$$ \text{id} = \prod_{p \;\text{prime}} \Delta[p] $$

In the above $\Delta[p]$ is the function that sends $0$ to $0$, $1$ to $1$, and every prime $q$ to $q$ if $p=q$ and $1$ otherwise.

The existence of the above infinite product means that any purported factorization of $\text{id}$ (which must be finite) can be further broken down. Thus $\text{id}$ doesn't have a unique factorization up to units, thus $R$ is not a UFD.

Comment: This is a bit of a tangent, but you might be interested in the diagram I created for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656540).

Comment: @joriki A comment on your answer also references [this magnificent diagram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045800/is-all-euclidean-domain-local/2045817#2045817).