# Counterexamples in Ring theory

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request

I am looking for a document or book containing some chart similar ( but more extensive) to this

(Obviously not my chart. Found it here:http://facstaff.cbu.edu/wschrein/media/M402%20Notes/M402C13.pdf; just using for reference)
[image]

so that I can quickly check for counterexamples for rings of a given kind.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29006/counterexamples-in-algebra might be useful. Or https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/counterexamples+in+algebra#ring_theory or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334835/counterexamples-in-algebra

Comment: See also Hutchins's book [Examples of Commutative Rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95935/242) (here examples means mostly counterexamples), which is based on his thesis under Kaplansky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [database of Ring Theory](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/) is the most thorough collection that I know of. Under the "Properties" tab you can search for rings that do, as well as rings that do not have one of the listed properties.